# Weird behavior with C++/CLI and friend assemblies

Tags: .net, c++-cli

I am writing two C++/CLI assemblies. One assembly has a base class with some internal virtual methods. The other assembly is marked as friend and contains derived class.

When I try to override the internal virtual method, the compiler is forcing me to change the visibility level to public.

What is going on? Why do I have to do this?

Code:

```
// Assembly 1 "FriendAssemblyBase"
namespace FriendAssemblyTest
{
    public ref class BaseClass
    {
    internal:
        BaseClass()
        {
        }

        virtual void DoSomething()
        {
        }
    };
}

// Allow "FriendAsseblyDerived" to see internals
[assembly:  ::System::Runtime::CompilerServices::InternalsVisibleToAttribute(
"FriendAssemblyDerived, PublicKey=0024000004800000940000000602000000240000525341310004000001000100a95fe809ecc53c3a826aa32e3ab1309f2ecae4b91dc649457d704e150f3a4007a151ffe28852f947803dd1a1586c5c0ae2c9688bd76299857ee65ff7efb14905e03b33664a42e2fa1074080c3bad971623514ab6dd9fc4e4343ba7fb98884ecce45f96b71e5f1b55de88e36483274aa71c740fdfb14aacaada6ca22cb39bf9a2")];

// ----------------
// Assembly 2. "FriendAssemblyDerived". Strongly named and signed
#using "FriendAssemblyBase.dll" as_friend
namespace FriendAssemblyTest
{

    public ref class Derived : BaseClass
    {
    public:
        Derived() {}

        void Foo()
        {
            DoSomething();
        }

    internal: // <-- Causes C3252 (cannot reduce visibility of virtuals)
        virtual void DoSomething() override
        {
        }
    };
}
```

Comment: Can you provide a pair of dummy classes to demonstrate how your classes are deriving/containing one another?

Comment: I added some code to illustrate.

Comment: What part of "post the attribute declaration" was unclear?  Bye.

Comment: Added "attribute declaration". Not sure how that detail will help anyone answer the question...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because other classes in `FriendAssemblyBase` can call `BaseClass.DoSomething`.

the Liskov Substitution Principle says that anything that can be done with the base class must be doable with every derived class.  Do `DerivedClass.DoSomething` has to be visible to `FriendAssemblyBase`.  The only way that can happen is with `public:`.

Comment: But can't it just call its own virtual function? How is this different than protected visibility?

Comment: **Other** classes in `FriendAssemblyBase`, not necessarily `BaseClass` itself, can call the function.  That wouldn't be true for protected.